# I want to optimize this query by using proper indexes

Tags: mysql

```
delete from cards_package_breakup 
where cards_package_id in 
    (select id from cards_package where cards_package.cards_id=13);
```

I have no direct relation of cards_package_breakup table with any table with which I can match values and I want to delete data on the basis of inner query. I have applied proper indices on columns but not using that indices? the main problem is index.. any one can help

Comment: @shoaib. I understand English isn't your first language but the question is a bit vague. Can you look at it again and make it a bit  more concise and tell us what your problem actually is?. Ta

Comment: i am asking i have applied indices on required columns but it is not using any indices..any more explanations?

Comment: can i use this query in procedure as using 'in' is expensive.any other alternate solution for the same query?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you've got proper indexes which allow you to relate your tables to eachother, so you could try modifying your query as per below:

```
DELETE FROM cards_package_breakup AS cpb
   LEFT JOIN cards_package AS cp ON cp.id = cpb.cardspackage_id
   WHERE cpb.cards_id = 13;
```

Where needed correct the fieldnames to match your exact schema, but the above will connect your two tables, and delete from `cards_package_breakup` the lines which match your criteria.

Comment: not completely,but updated query provides me a clue.i rewrite my query.now it is working fine.thanks